# Async Web Api Action Returning Prematurely

Tags: c#, mongodb, asp.net-web-api, async-await, restsharp

I am writing a nuget package that will consume a REST API I wrote. Im having some difficulty in calling it asynchronously using RestSharp.

I have the following controller method:

```
    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetFeatureByIdAsync(string id)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(id))
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("id-Null", "The id parameter cannot be null.");
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        var feature = await _director.GetFeatureById(id);

        if (feature == null)
            return NotFound();

        var model = new ViewModel<Feature>(feature);
        return Ok(model);
    }
```

I have the follow class library in a seperate solution:

```
    public async Task<bool> IsSwitchEnabledAsync(string name)
    {
        string fullyFormedUrl = $"{_url}/{name}";

        var client = new RestClient(fullyFormedUrl) { Encoding = Encoding.UTF8 };

        var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET) { RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json };

        var result = await client.ExecuteTaskAsync<FeatureViewModel>(request);

        var message = $"Response: {result.StatusCode}, {result.ResponseStatus}, " +
                          $"\n\nError: {result.ErrorException}, {result.ErrorMessage} " +
                          $"\n\nData: {result.Content}";
        Debug.WriteLine(message);

        return result.Data != null;
    }
```

I have the following basic integration test sandbox:

```
[TestFixture]
public class Sandbox
{
    private FeatureSwitch _sut;

    [OneTimeSetUp]
    public void Setup()
    {
        const string machineName = "localhost";
        const int port = 5000;
        _sut = new FeatureSwitch(machineName, port);
    }

    [Test]
    public async Task ShouldReturnTrue()
    {
        var result = await _sut.IsSwitchEnabledAsync("Release_US501_AddUser");
        result.Should().BeTrue();
    }
}
```

I am looking for a little education on the best approach on how to call the API correctly? As my sandbox code is failing with an Internal Server 500 Error. This is because the api method is waiting for the nested async call to complete. So the initial request returns back to the sandbox code before the nested api call has a chance to complete.

The sandbox test code needs to wait for the API to return a result. At the moment it is not doing this.

So what is the correct approach here?

**UPDATE:** *My issue was down to incorrect usage of a Mongo library method.*

Comment: `This is because the api method is waiting for the nested async call to complete.` - No, the response is not sent until the `async` method completes. There is something else causing the 500 error.

Comment: A `500` *typically* means an exception is being thrown and not handled. Have you debugged the exception in the Web API (assuming there is one)?

Comment: Thanks Chaps - let me dig further into it.

Comment: I had nested .ToLower() method that was causing an Invalid Operation Exception to be thrown and oddly when i was debugging the error was not being surfaced so i could not figure out what was causing the issue?.

Comment: @IbrarMumtaz so does that mean that you have solved your own issue and that the problem that can no longer be reproduced?

Answer (score 0):

My issue came from a .chained method call on a Mongo library method:

I was trying to do the following:

```
Collection.Find(x => x.Name.ToLower().Equals(name.ToLower())
```

The code compiled but it was throwing an exception that VS studio 17 was not breaking on so i had no idea where the issue was occurring. With code lens turned on, I noticed that the failed requests highlighted in red. This opened an App Insights window which highlighted a break down of 4 `InvalidOperationException()` that had been thrown. That's how i discovered what the Internal Server Error 500 was about.

Anyways that's how i solved Async Web API problem - it was my first time using it on a web service so I had no idea what the expected default behaviour ought to be.